# How do I set the memory at an address to a particular value?

Tags: python-3.x, pointers, ctypes

I have an `int` representing a memory address. I want to the equivalent of C's `*p = foo`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the type of whatever you want to store there. Do you want a `float`? A `double`? A `void_p`?

Create a C object of that type from its address, and update its value:

```
ctypes.c_float.from_address(p) = foo
```